# Python. Neural Network with 2 Hidden Layers

Tags: python, networking

I added a second hidden layer to the neural network based on the book "Make Your Own Neural Network" (Tariq Rashid; https://github.com/makeyourownneuralnetwork/makeyourownneuralnetwork). The following configuration of neurons is obtained: 784 + 200 + 100 + 10.

```
# neural network class definition
class neuralNetwork:
    
    
    # initialise the neural network
    def __init__(self, inputnodes, hiddennodes1, hiddennodes2, outputnodes, learningrate):
        # set number of nodes in each input, hidden, output layer
        self.inodes = inputnodes
        self.hnodes1 = hiddennodes1
        self.hnodes2 = hiddennodes2
        self.onodes = outputnodes
        
        # link weight matrices, wih and who
        # weights inside the arrays are w_i_j, where link is from node i to node j in the next layer
        # w11 w21
        # w12 w22 etc 
        self.wih = numpy.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.inodes, -0.5), (self.hnodes1, self.inodes))
        self.whh = numpy.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.hnodes1, -0.5), (self.hnodes2, self.hnodes1))
        self.who = numpy.random.normal(0.0, pow(self.hnodes2, -0.5), (self.onodes, self.hnodes2))

        # learning rate
        self.lr = learningrate
        
        # activation function is the sigmoid function
        self.activation_function = lambda x: scipy.special.expit(x)
        
        pass

    
    # train the neural network
    def train(self, inputs_list, targets_list):
        # convert inputs list to 2d array
        inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
        targets = numpy.array(targets_list, ndmin=2).T
        
        # calculate signals into 1 hidden layer
        hidden_1_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        # calculate the signals emerging from 1 hidden layer
        hidden_1_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_1_inputs)
        
        # calculate signals into 2 hidden layer
        hidden_2_inputs = numpy.dot(self.whh, hidden_1_outputs)
        # calculate the signals emerging from 2 hidden layer
        hidden_2_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_2_inputs)
        
        # calculate signals into final output layer
        final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.who, hidden_2_outputs)
        # calculate the signals emerging from final output layer
        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)
        
        # output layer error is the (target - actual)
        output_errors = targets - final_outputs
        # hidden2 layer error is the output_errors, split by weights, recombined at hidden2 nodes
        hidden_2_errors = numpy.dot(self.who.T, output_errors) 
        # hidden1 layer error is the output_errors, split by weights, recombined at hidden1 nodes
        hidden_1_errors = numpy.dot(self.whh.T, hidden_2_errors) 
        
        # update the weights for the links between the 2 hidden and output layers
        self.who += self.lr * numpy.dot((output_errors * final_outputs * (1.0 - final_outputs)), numpy.transpose(hidden_2_outputs))
        
        # update the weights for the links between the hiddens layers
        self.whh += self.lr * numpy.dot((hidden_2_errors * hidden_2_outputs * (1.0 - hidden_2_outputs)), numpy.transpose(hidden_1_outputs))
        
        # update the weights for the links between the input and hidden layers
        self.wih += self.lr * numpy.dot((hidden_1_errors * hidden_1_outputs * (1.0 - hidden_1_outputs)), numpy.transpose(inputs))
        
        pass

    
    # query the neural network
    def query(self, inputs_list):
        # convert inputs list to 2d array
        inputs = numpy.array(inputs_list, ndmin=2).T
        
        # calculate signals into 1 hidden layer
        hidden_1_inputs = numpy.dot(self.wih, inputs)
        # calculate the signals emerging from 1 hidden layer
        hidden_1_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_1_inputs)
        
        # calculate signals into 2 hidden layer
        hidden_2_inputs = numpy.dot(self.whh, hidden_1_outputs)
        # calculate the signals emerging from 2 hidden layer
        hidden_2_outputs = self.activation_function(hidden_2_inputs)
        
        # calculate signals into final output layer
        final_inputs = numpy.dot(self.who, hidden_2_outputs)
        # calculate the signals emerging from final output layer
        final_outputs = self.activation_function(final_inputs)
        
        return final_outputs
```

I train a neural network on 100 MNIST samples and test on 10 samples. They get a worse result (0.5) than in a neural network with one hidden layer (0.6-0.7; the configuration of neurons: 784 + 200 + 10 ). Please point out the errors in my neural network implementation.

Comment: An NN with more hidden layers doesn't necessarily give better results. On the contrary, it is likely more prone to overfitting. Look into strategies to avoid overfitting, notably dropout layers.

Comment: Thank you, but I want to make sure that my neural network implementation is correct.